# Hilt Inject field into any class with no scope

Tags: android, dependency-injection, field, dagger-hilt

Suppose that I have a class A

```
class A ()
```

I want to inject an instance of `A` as a field into class `B` and let Hilt or Dagger to handle it.

```
Class B {

  @Inject lateinit var a: A 

}
```

Let say class B is a plain class, has no context, e.g viewmodel or anything, what are the proper steps (if possible) so I can use the instance `a` without manual init.

Answer (score 1):

If you can access constructor of class B you can pass as an argument like that:

```
class B @Inject constructor(
    private val classA : A 
){
     //...
}
```

Otherwise you can use `@EntryPoints`.
To learn more details about `@EntryPoint`, you can click the link below:

https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#not-supported